# Symfony try to save log in the bad place

Tags: symfony-1.4, apache2.4

I'm installing a Symfony 1.4 on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I'm not realy familiar with apache configuration.

I'm put a symbolic link like that : /var/www/symfony1_test -> /home/user/dev/symfony1_test

Now I want to access my site with localhost:9494/frontend_dev.php

So my virtualhost is :

```
listen 127.0.0.1:9494
<VirtualHost *:9494>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/symfony1_test/web"                                                

     <Directory "/var/www/symfony1_test/web">                                       
        AllowOverride All                                                           
        Require all granted
        Allow from  127.0.0.1                                                     
        Allow from  localhost                                                     
     </Directory>                                                                   

     Alias /sf /var/www/symfony1_test/web/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
     <Directory "/var/www/symfony1_test/web/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
        AllowOverride All                                                           
        Require all granted
        Allow from  127.0.0.1                                                     
        Allow from  localhost                                                     
     </Directory>                                                                 
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go in localhost:9494/frontend_dev.php I have this error :

```
Unable to open the log file "/var/www/log/frontend_dev.log" for writing.
```

Why symfony is trying to create log in /var/www/log and not /var/www/symfony1_test/log ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

frontend_dev.log is the application log, not the Apache Log (or web server log).

The application log is configured into your frontend/config/factories.yml configuration file. Check the path of your log in the file.